# Can I highlight an invalid form field without assigning a message for it?

Tags: 6, forms

I have a form which presents three input fields which are later combined into a single phone number. When that phone number doesn't validate (doesn't match `/^\d{10}$/`), I want to show a single message saying the phone number is incorrectly formatted, but I want to highlight all three input fields. Is this possible? The best I have come up with is this:

```
form_set_error('firstBox', $theMessage);
form_set_error('secondBox', " ");
form_set_error('thirdBox', " ");
```

This way, all fields are highlighted and I get the message only once, but I still get bullet points for the *empty* messages...

[image]

Is there a better solution for this?

Comment: Are these in a fieldset?  If so, you should be able to set the form error on that (eg, the parent) and it should cascade down through to the individual fields with just one error message.  http://drupal.org/node/678816 talks to this briefly.

Comment: They are in a fieldset, but they are not alone. Indeed, the `phoneNumber` fieldset also has a field for the extension and another one for the `category` (residential, work, etc). I suppose I could add a fieldset in there to solve my problem though, but I'll wait to see if there's a better solution first.

Answer (score 1):

D'oh.  In Drupal 6 at least, just call form_set_error(FIELD) without the message and it should highlight the field and not set a message.  You are sending a space, so you are getting a space as a message.

Code in Question:

```
function form_set_error($name = NULL, $message = '', $reset = FALSE) {
  static $form = array();
  if ($reset) {
    $form = array();
  }
  if (isset($name) && !isset($form[$name])) {
    $form[$name] = $message;
    if ($message) {
      drupal_set_message($message, 'error');
    }
  }
  return $form;
}
```

Comment: a quick look at the code in Drupal 7 suggests the same behavior, just call form_set_error() with only the first argument.

Comment: I just tried that and the fields are not highlighted at all if I call `form_set_error` with the first argument only.

Comment: Grr...  Sorry :(

Comment: Well, you could go this route:  http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21form.inc/function/form_get_errors/7  and clean up messages and errors manually.